# Not able to stop AJAX request called from setTimout

Tags: jquery

I have seen many posts regarding aborting AJAX requests using `.abort()` function such as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery?lq=1), but it just doesn't work for me.

I make repeated AJAX calls after every 30 seconds using setTimout, and there is a point where I would like to stop the repeating calls from occurring based on a condition.

Am I doing something wrong or is it that `.abort()` has been deprecated? I'm using jquery version 1.9.1.

Comment: Are you using a setTimeout function to call them?

Comment: Yes, and i use that in the complete function

Comment: Have you tried using a setInterval instead, storing the id, clearInterval at the point when you do not want to call it again? [This may help as well..?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/446626/1257652) Without more context and some code to see what is going on, I'm not sure how else to help. :/

Comment: Oh yes! It's working perfectly now! Amazing to see that using just setInterval instead of setTimeout made all the difference.. thanks a lot :)

Comment: Let me write up a solution for you since this solved the problem so you can mark an answer, I'll edit your question a bit and set this up to help someone else in the future.

Comment: There we go, all fixed up I think! Maybe you could add a simplified example of your code as well?

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution as an answer, I was about to suggest that. The first code block in your answer almost matches my code. Should I edit my question to include the code anyway?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33320/discussion-between-rahul-dole-and-brett-weber)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
var xhr = null;
ajaxOfTheSort = function
(
   xhr = $.ajax
   (
      success : function()
      {
         /* Do something */ 
         setTimeout( ajaxOfTheSort, 30000 );
      }
   );
)

if (/* condition */)
   xhr.abort();
```

try using setInterval() :

```
var oInterval = setInterval
(
    function()
    {
       if (/* condition */)
          clearInterval( oInterval );
       else
          $.ajax
          (
             success : function() { /* Do something */ }
          );
    },
    300000
)
```